# Find Enum Value by Passed Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I have an enum like this :

```
public enum Priority
{
   Low = 0,
   Medium = 1,
   Urgent = 2 
}
```

And I want to get the for example `Priority.Low` by passing like `Enum.GetEnumVar(Priority,0)` which should return `Priority.Low`

How can I accomplish that ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply cast it to the *enum* type:

```
int value = 0;
Priority priority = (Priority)value;
// priority == Priority.Low
```

Note that you can cast any int to Priority, not only those which have a name: `(Priority)42` is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
Priority fromInt = (Priority)0;
Assert.That(fromInt, Is.EqualTo(Priority.Low));
```

Also, this works:

```
Priority fromString = (Priority)Enum.Parse(typeof(Priority), "Low");
Assert.That(fromString, Is.EqualTo(Priority.Low));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think Assert class is used for Unit Testing, you intended to verify its status ?

Comment: I ran the code in a unit test to make sure I didn't have a typo before I cut and pasted. I kept the Asserts because I think they communicate what I was trying to show. Similar to how dtb used the following comment: // priority == Priority.Low.